# Counting click on button

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I want to ask what function or another have to write so that every time I pressed the Start button (function:addbutton), the other button to exit (function:addButton2) to change its title to how many times I press the start?

```
class DroppingFrame extends JFrame   {
  public DroppingFrame() {  
    int clicked=0;
    String b="a";
    setSize(1400, 700);
    setTitle("Dropping");

    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
      public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        System.exit(0);
      }
    });
    Container contentPane = getContentPane();
    canvas = new JPanel();
    contentPane.add(canvas, "Center");
    JPanel p = new JPanel();

    addButton(p, "Drop ball", clicked, new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        //addButton.setText(String.valueOf(++clicked));

        Ball b = new Ball(canvas);
        // if(b== new Ball(canvas)){
        // clicked++;
        // }
        b.start();    
      }  
    });

    addButton2(p, b, clicked, new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        canvas.setVisible(false);
        System.exit(0);
      }
    });

    contentPane.add(p, "South");
  }

  public void addButton(Container c, String title, int i, ActionListener a) {
    //i++;
    //title = Integer.toString(i);
    JButton b = new JButton(title);
    c.add(b);
    b.addActionListener(a);
  }

  public void addButton2(Container c, String title, int i, ActionListener a ) {
    i++;
    title = Integer.toString(i);
    JButton b = new JButton(title);
    c.add(b);
    b.addActionListener(a);
  }

  private JPanel canvas;
}
```

Comment: where is the issue? Simply call `btn2.setText(String.valueOf(++clicked));` inside the `btn1.addActionListener()`

Comment: Thank you verry much but it is not working...

Comment: I refresh the cource, you can see the comments, this is what I've tried.

Comment: if for you will be easier, I can show the whole code of the program and the  condition of the program?

Comment: Look at my post. What I am trying to say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My preference would be:

1. Make `clicked` a class field - that way you can access it and mutate it inside the event handler
2. Create a class field for a button
3. Refactor the `addButton` method so there is only one of them - this makes your code tidier:
4. Change the method return type to return the button created, then you decide if you store it or not from the caller. This just smells nicer.

The code looks like:

```
class DroppingFrame extends JFrame {
    final JPanel canvas = new JPanel();
    JButton button2;
    int clicked = 0;
    public DroppingFrame() {
        setSize(1400, 700);
        setTitle("Dropping");

        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        Container contentPane = getContentPane();
        contentPane.add(canvas, "Center");
        JPanel p = new JPanel();

        addButton(p, "Drop ball", clicked, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                Ball b = new Ball(canvas);
                b.start();
                button2.setText(String.valueOf(++clicked));
            }  
        });

        button2 = addButton(p, String.valueOf(clicked), clicked, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                canvas.setVisible(false);
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        contentPane.add(p, "South");
    }

    public JButton addButton(Container c, String title, int i, ActionListener a) {
        JButton b = new JButton(title);
        c.add(b);
        b.addActionListener(a);
        return b;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is just the most elegant way, but let him also work with it:) but +1

Comment: @user3671447 - you are welcome. I left plenty for you to play with still - your add button method has an unused `int i` parameter, for instance, and `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` is worth looking into instead of `addWindowListener`, as Braj's answer notes.

Answer (score 1):

It requires the reference of the second button so that start button can update its text.

Keep it simple:

- Use `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` instead of adding `WindowListener` to close the window.
- Use `JFrame#dispose` to close the JFrame programmatically.
- *Favor Composition over Inheritance* It means if you are not overriding any logic/implementation of the existing class then don't extend it.
- There is no meaning of creating separate method for adding each component. Either make the method generic or simply remove it.

Sample code:

```
public class DroppingFrame {    
    private int clicked = 0;
    public DroppingFrame() {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
        JPanel p = new JPanel();

        final JButton btn2 = new JButton(String.valueOf(clicked));
        btn2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                frame.dispose();
            }
        });

        JButton btn1 = new JButton("Drop ball");
        btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                btn2.setText(String.valueOf(++clicked));
            }
        });

        p.add(btn1);
        p.add(btn2);
        contentPane.add(p, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }    
}
```

Comment: Worth noting that this exact code ordering may have the undesired consequence of reversing the display order of the buttons compared to the original code.

Comment: @AndyBrown Yes you are right. Let me update my post.

Answer (score 0):

It's not correct.. addButton always creates a new button and its reference is lost.. you should make it class-scoped.

So make a class variable:

```
JButton button = new JButton();
```

Change your function:

```
public void addButton(Container c, String title, int i, ActionListener a) {
  button.setText(title);
  c.add(button);
   button.addActionListener(a);
 }
```

And also change your actionPerformed override:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    button.setText(String.valueOf(++clicked));
    ....
});
```

Comment: Look at this line `button.setText(clicked++);`. Is it valid?